# How do I join these queries?

Tags: mysql, join, outer-join

query1:

```
SELECT category.id, category.name, category.level, category.description, category.cat1, category.cat2, category.cat3, category.cat4, category.pri_color, category.sec_color, category.last_report AS report_id FROM category, reports_category_layout WHERE category.id = reports_category_layout.catID AND reports_category_layout.site_code = 'las'
```

query2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category.id, COUNT(forum.id) AS posts, SUM(forum.view) AS views FROM category, forum WHERE category.id = forum.catID AND forum.approved = 'yes' AND forum.site_code = 'las' GROUP BY category.id
```

query3:

```
SELECT forum.catID, forum.title, forum.paragraph, forum.created, users.alias, forum.userID FROM forum, users, forum_cache WHERE forum.catID = forum_cache.catID AND forum.id = forum_cache.last_report AND users.id = forum.userID AND forum.approved = 'yes'
```

Essentially, I am unsure about the syntax to join these properly.  I have written a query that simply joins them, but in the case that the forum cache table contains an unapproved forum id, it will simply not return the entire row.

what I really need is for query1 and query2 to be left joined on the category id, and for query 3 to be left outer joined on id = catID.

Answer (score 0):

query1:

```
SELECT category.id, category.name, category.level, category.description, category.cat1, category.cat2, category.cat3, category.cat4, category.pri_color, category.sec_color, category.last_report AS report_id 
FROM category c
LEFT OUTER JOIN reports_category_layout rcl on c.id = rcl.catID
    AND rcl.site_code = 'las'
```

query2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT category.id, COUNT(forum.id) AS posts, SUM(forum.view) AS views 
FROM category c
LEFT OUTER JOIN forum f on c.id = f.catID 
    AND f.approved = 'yes' 
    AND f.site_code = 'las' 
GROUP BY c.id
```

query3:

Not really sure what you are asking for on this, but took a stab at it:

```
SELECT forum.catID, forum.title, forum.paragraph, forum.created, users.alias, forum.userID 
FROM forum f
INNER JOIN users u on u.id = f.userID
LEFT OUTER JOIN forum_cache fc on f.catID = fc.catID 
    and f.id = fc.last_report 
WHERE f.approved = 'yes'
```

Comment: Perhaps I was not being clear:

I want to left join the results of query1 and query2 together
Then
left outer join that result with the results of query 3.

I have a functional understanding of what it is I want to do, but I can't get the syntax right.